# Lamp transformer fix makes monitor shut down

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, identification, troubleshooting, lamp

I fixed a lamp transformer case (230 V to 12 V) by making a 3D printed one. I measured 12 V at the secondary coil and the lamp is working well.

The thing is, when I plug the transformer to a power strip where my PC monitor is plugged in, my monitor shuts down or makes electric arc noises. What did I do wrong?

The lamp is directly plugged in at the secondary coil. Maybe I swapped a connection at the primary or the secondary or both.

I noticed there is a component (I don't know what it is) that could be the issue.

[image]

Comment: You didn't change anything about the transformer or this extra component, right? Just put it inside a 3D-printed plastic case?

Comment: That overhanging component with the bare wires looks like a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: That disc component (MOV?) is probably making contact with the grounded core of the transformer and shorting the output.

Comment: Was this component in this position (touching the transformer core) when you originally found it, or did you bend the wires to make it like that?

Comment: (It's possible that it could be something like a thermal switch, and maybe it is designed so it touches the core on purpose, to detect the temperature. On the other hand it's possible that it isn't)

Comment: This component was already here and wired as the picture. It was bent like that. I though at first it is a bimetal thermal switch.